# I'm trying to get the name of a server in Weblogic to use in my log4j Config

Tags: java, log4j, java-ee-6, weblogic11g

I'm using log4j in a project that is being deployed to a clustered Weblogic 11g environment, and I'm trying to get the name of the server that has the app deployed on it to use for logs. I seem to remember that there is a way to get the running server name, but it is escaping me... here is the line from my log4j config for where I want to send the log output:

```
log4j.appender.MyRollingAppender.File=servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/serverName.log
```

Right now everything is going into `serverName.log` for each server, but I would like to have the output go into a server specific file, i.e, `server1.log` for activity on server 1 and `server2.log` on server 2.

Comment: Why not just use the variable name instead of a static logfile name ? `/${weblogic.Name}/logs/${weblogic.Name}.log`

Comment: @Kal ID-10-T moment on my part, I don't know where my mind is today. Pose your question in the form of an answer and I will accept it, and vote it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the variable instead of a static file name

```
log4j.appender.MyRollingAppender.File=servers/${weblogic.Name}/logs/${weblogic.Name}.log
```